# Regex expression to match multiple coordinates separated by spaces

Tags: c++, regex, validation, input

I am trying to learn regex for my project I am working on to use it for input validation because I have been told that using regex is one of the best ways to do input validation.

So, I am trying to make sure a string contains an unknown number of coordinates which are separated by a space. An example of what the input will look like is `2,2 23.45,6 45,21.65 2,2` I'm not sure if it matters, but the last coordinate will always match the first. There can't be any symbols or extraneous spaces or commas. Only a decimal numbers split with a comma, followed by a space or an endline character.

I realize that this is probably quite a complex expression, and I am pretty much jumping into regex blind, so any help with this would be really appreciated. I am programming in c++ if that changes anything. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I had forgotten about the possibility of negative numbers and newline characters. I also accept negative numbers and newline characters in the input.
So the input `-2.3,2 34,-2 -2.3,2\n` is acceptable. Thank you to everyone so far for the help.

Comment: It seems like you can have spaces as well as commas separating numbers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen They are technically ordered pairs. So I need 2 numbers that are separated by a comma. And then if there are more than 1 ordered pair, those are separated by a space.

Comment: What about negative numbers, exponential notation?   You almost have to write the expression yourself to describe what the syntax is.  Is "+4.3,-." a valid component?

Comment: @JohnGriffin sorry, negative numbers are also acceptable. I had forgotten about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?,(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)? \d+(?:\.\d+)?,)*\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Note: The regex `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` matches any number, possibly having a decimal component.  The `?:` inside the parenthesis marks the quantity as a non capture group.  This tells the regex engine to not capture what is inside, as we don't want to actually capture anything here.  This possibly will result in a more efficient regex.

Comment: Although incomplete, e.g. sign spec and newlines, let's suppose that this is the answer.  Now, how is someone that does not understand regular expressions going to confirm the answer?   Still, it's generous of you.

Comment: I hadn't thought of newlines, and the OP did not mention the possibility of negatives.

Comment: +1 for regex101, something that allows the questioner to learn regex instead of trying to simply fulfill it.  I'm bookmarking it.

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems to work for what I asked. How would I adapt this to work for negative numbers as well? I had forgotten about the possibility of negatives. Also, there is the possibility that there is a newline character. I apologize for these oversights in my question.

Comment: After messing around with it for a while, it seems like `^-?\\d*\\.{0,1}\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?,(?:-?\\d*\\.{0,1}\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)? -?\\d*\\.{0,1}\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?,)*-?\\d*\\.{0,1}\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` works with negative and positive numbers too. Thank you very much for the help. I wouldn't have been able to do it without you.